# twig round function not always working in a Webform

Tags: webforms

I have a Webform that makes use of some computed fields.

Here is an example of the computed result:

```
{% if data.rent_amount and data.rent_period %}
 <span>$
  {{ (data.rent_amount / data.rent_period) *14 |round(2)}}
 </span>
{% else %}
 <span>$0.00</span>
{% endif %}
```

This works "most" of the time. But sporadically on mobile devices the `round(2)` function doesn't fire leading to bad-looking results. There are 5 or so computed fields all printed out together so it gets rather confusing to look at.

I have been able to reproduce this intermittently on both Android and Apple devices.

Comment: There isn’t a question here.

Comment: What do you mean? The round function is not being applied sporadically and I can't figure out why. Is it the way I've asked about the issue?